# *Deja vu* all over again

Tags: redundancy, foreign-phrases

"*Deja vu* all over again" is an example of either a semi-literate (when the speaker does not know what *deja vu* means) or a jocular use (when the speaker tries to be funny).

Can you give similar examples of (possibly double) usage?

Comment: You can hace deja vu more than once, even about the same thing.

Comment: You can have deja vu more than once, even about the same thing.

Comment: *"Again, it is repeated."*

Comment: Well, the phrase comes from Yogi Berra, so feel free to just google him and read up on all the other things he said.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: But I have this nagging feeling it's not *really* deja vu if you hace the naggimg feeling it's slightly different the second time around.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - trying to type on tablet at the beach.  Damn glare.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's nothing wrong with the phrase (I get deja vus on monthly basis), but I see what you mean. I vaguely recall the original sentence went something like "It was another deja vu all over again".

Getting back to your original question - I've always loved how you can *fall down* in English. Like you could *fall up*.

There's some nice examples of tautology in formal use, eg. *terms and conditions*, *null and void*. I seem to have heard somebody argue that the *whether... or...* structure also follows the above, tautological suit, as it's enough to say *whether*.